# Read an email with ruby Gmail's API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, ruby-on-rails-5, gmail-api

I want to get the full message text not the snippet. This is what I do.

```
#List messages
@messages = @gmail.list_user_messages("#{current_user.email}",q: "from:addres")

#Get messages send by 'addres'
<% @messages.messages.each do |msg| %>
        <% msg = @gmail.get_user_message("#{current_user.email}",msg.id,format:"full")%>
<%end%>
```

Some help?

Comment: What is `@gmail`?

Comment: Do try to avoid using the `"#{x}"` anti-pattern. In this case you can use `current_user.email` without the pointless clutter around it. You can also avoid opening and closing the ERB tags if you're going to do multiple lines of code: Open once at the start, close one at the end of the code block.

Comment: This is gmail @thesecretmaster : gmail = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new is used to initialize the API

Comment: Did you figure out the answer to this? Thanks.